# jQueryUI - Resize Dialog after AJAX Load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Im trying to write a quick plugin that will load some AJAX content into a jQuery UI dialog and resize and center the dialog accordingly.  Here's the gist of what it does:

```
$(mySelector).html('Loading...').load(options.url, function() {

    element = $(mySelector);

    element.dialog('option', 'height', element.height() + 50);
    element.dialog('option', 'width', element.width());
    element.dialog('option', 'position', 'center');

});
```

The height seems to be OK (adding some for padding the dialog adds) but the width is ALWAYS 274 no matter what.  I think the dialog itself is setting the size limits on it.  How can I set it to what the natural width of the loaded content would be?

**Edit/Addition:**
It is returning the default size of the modal.  Because even if it contains content that is wider (say a 500px image), the parent container (mySelector) may not be that wide (in FF at least), so it was always the default (300 - padding = 274).  Is there any way to auto-detect what the width of the returned content would be at a minimum without it scrolling?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They key was to call open again after the content has been loaded, then re-center it.  This will cause the dialog to do it's magic and resize everything properly and re-center itself.  I'll post a plugin here once I get it cleaned up.

Answer (score 9):

I used to have the same problem. If I remember, you need to first load the dialog and then load the content in it. That way, the dialog will auto resize to its content (with width=auto).

More less like this (tested):

```
var $dialog; //Must be at the global scope
function dialog(url) {
    $dialog.dialog("option", "width", "auto");
    $dialog.dialog("option", "height", "auto");
    $.get(url,{},function(html) {
        $dialog.html(html);
        $dialog.dialog("open");
    });
}

$(function() {
    //Initialize (without showing it)
    var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog" title=""></div>').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

Then you can do this:

```
dialog(someURL);
```

Comment: Do you mean load the content then initialize the dialog?  Because I am creating the dialog and then loading the content currently.  It'd be great if there was an auto-resize method for the dialog but I can't find anything like that.

Comment: I updated and tested the code. Just include the JQuery-ui and dialog files. It works :) One advantage of doing it like this is that you can change the URL (even when the dialog is open) and it will resize itself automatically. No more code needed.

Comment: Thanks, that got me in the right track... the key was calling open (again in my case) on the callback after you do your $.get.  My solution is actually going to be a little different than yours because of a couple other requirements... I'll post it here when it's done.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but this is my working solution:

```
$("#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',

        create: function(){
                var content = '<h1>This is some Content</h1>';
                $('.content', this).replaceWith(content);

        buttons: {
            Ok: function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

The trick was to insert the dialog content in the 'create' handler.